# Multiple input types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
type InputValue<Output> = Output | Promise<Output> | (() => Output | Promise<Output>);

async function test<Output>(data: InputValue<Output>): Promise<Output> {
    return typeof data === 'function' ? data() : data
}
```

this gives error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type '(() => Output | Promise<Output>) | (Output & Function)' are callable.
    Type 'Output & Function' has no call signatures.
```

technically propably works ok, but I would like to get types also happy. I think it's someway related that Output type itself can be anything (even function)?

Comment: You're right; if `Output` is a function type, then you could be calling it incorrectly. You can fix it by checking if `Output` is a function type inside `InputValue`: https://tsplay.dev/wOlRzN

Comment: @pink it's interesting that this works; I guess it narrows to `InputValue<Output> & Function` which is then callable as if it were `Function` (you can call `data("oopsieDoodle")`) which is unsafe but at least it suppresses the error.  I'd have gone the "try to approximate `NonFunction` as a specific type" route like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG8R2w), which has its own problems. Not sure which approach if any the OP wants to see as an answer.

Comment: I think both cases are ok if I do build function to "solve" actual value, but if it's internal part then it would ne nice that it's still proper types. I'm still buzzled why it adds (Output & Function) type in there.

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed; are you happy with pink's suggestion? If so I will disengage and let them write up an answer.  If not, are you happy with my suggestion? If so I will write up an answer.  If not, I'll disengage.  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz both works great, but I think this sounds more like internal issue on TS, as I should be able to work with InputValue<Function> too without having issue with type.

Comment: TS is working correctly. If you have a value of type `O | (()=>O)` for generic `O`, and see that it's a function, you can't narrow to `()=>O` *unless you know that `O` cannot be a function type itself*.  That's a logic issue and not a TS limitation.  `InputValue<Function>` presumes that you know `O` is `Function`, but such knowledge is  unavailable inside the body of a generic function.  I'm still not sure how to proceed here, but I'm inclined to just disengage since your response wasn't a clear endorsement of either solution.

Comment: @jcalz just needed bit more coffee and thinking, yeah true it can't be function as Output type because we don't know if it's for callback getting value function or actual value function.

Comment: You've now changed the question completely? Please don't do that. If you have a new question, write a new one. And if the question is solved, write an answer, if anyone else hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Took me awhile to see that Output can't be function, but yeah then logic can't know if it's function to get value or callback function to return function reference.

```js
type Loadable<Output> = Output extends Function
    ? never
    : Output | Promise<Output> | (() => Output | Promise<Output>);

async function getLoadableValue<Output>(data: Loadable<Output>): Promise<Output> {
    return typeof data === 'function' ? data() : data
}
```

Thanks @pink and @jcalz for help!